# Launching Instance: VPC security groups may not be used for a non-VPC launch

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I'm attempting to create an instance in another region, but I get this error:

```
AWS Error Code: InvalidParameterCombination, AWS Error Message: VPC security groups may not be used for a non-VPC launch
```

Here is the code I'm executing.

```
RunInstancesRequest instancereq = new RunInstancesRequest();

instancereq.setInstanceType("m3.medium");
instancereq.setImageId("ami-37b1b45e");
instancereq.setMinCount(1);
instancereq.setMaxCount(1);

ArrayList<String> secgroup = new ArrayList<String>();        
instancereq.setKeyName("testkey");          
secgroup.add("testdefault");          
instancereq.setSecurityGroups(secgroup);

instancereq.setPlacement(getAzPlacement());        
RunInstancesResult instanceresult = ec2.runInstances(instancereq);
```

I've also tried, instead of using the name "testdefault", using the actual groupid `(sg-########)`, but I'll get an error saying that security group doesn't exist (which is wrong, it does).  Which, [based on the API doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/RunInstancesRequest.html#setSecurityGroups%28java.util.Collection%29), if using a non-default VPC, you should pass the actual groupid but I'll get an error like this:

```
InvalidGroup.NotFound, AWS Error Message: The security group 'sg-########' does not exist
```

If I use "default" as the `setSecurityGroups` it will use the default VPC. It just doesn't seem like like the groupid I'm passing, despite it being accurate.

Also, if I comment out the `setSecurityGroups` code, and use `setSubnetId` instead and pass the subnet id, it will create the instance just fine, but it goes into the "default" security group, not "testdefault" like I want.

All I'm trying to accomplish is creating an instance and having it use the already existing VPC group.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My Answer will focus on below statement:

> All I'm trying to accomplish is creating an instance and having it use the already existing VPC group.

So, as I understand, you want to launch an instance in a non-default VPC and assign it an existing VPC security group to it.

I am not a `java` guy, but I could do what you wanted in `ruby` as below.

```
require 'aws-sdk-core'
Aws.config = {
  :access_key_id => "my_access_key",
  :secret_access_key => "my_secret_key",
  :region => 'us-west-2'
}

ec2 = Aws::EC2.new

ec2.run_instances(
    min_count: 1,
    max_count: 1,
    image_id: 'ami-8635a9b6',
    instance_type: 't1.micro',
    placement: {
      availability_zone: 'us-west-2a'
    },
    network_interfaces: [
      {
        subnet_id: 'subnet-e881bd63',
        groups: ['sg-fd53bf5e'],
        device_index: 0,
        associate_public_ip_address: true
      }
    ],
    key_name: 'my-key'
).each do |resp|
  resp.instances.each do |x|
    puts x.instance_id
  end
end
```

Although this is a `Ruby` code, it is pretty straight forward and should give you some clear hints on how to go about doing it in `Java` as all these AWS SDKs are polling the same web service APIs.

I guess, the things that you should be concentrating in above code is:

```
  :region => 'us-west-2'
```

and

```
placement: {
  availability_zone: 'us-west-2a'
},
network_interfaces: [
  {
    subnet_id: 'subnet-e881bd63',
    groups: ['sg-fd53bf5e'],
    device_index: 0,
    associate_public_ip_address: true
  }
],
```

1. Make sure you explicitly specify the region.
2. Check how I have defined the subnet ID and security group ID. This code will launch my EC2 instance in `subnet-e881bd63` of my VPC and will apply VPC security group ID `sg-fd53bf5e` to its `0`th network interface. Besides, it will also assign a public IP address to my instance. (by default, it will not assign a public IP address when you launch instances in VPC).
3. FYI. When you launch instances in VPC, you must provide Security group ID instead of security group name.

Comment: This lead me to a solution, thank you for your time. The mistake I was making was discovered in the code you provided. I needed to use 'setSecurityGroupIds' to pass security group ids (eg 'sg-1234567'). 'setSecurityGroups' is a legacy method that can only be used when no subnet id is specified, and its value is expected to be a list of security group names (eg 'default'). Updated original post with Java solution.

Answer (score 3):

This same error occurs using the command line program so I'm adding a separate answer helped by QuickNull. Simply make sure you specify the security group and subnet. For example:

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-XXXXXXXX --count 1 --instance-type t1.micro --key-name XXXXXXXX --security-group-ids sg-XXXXXXXX --subnet-id subnet-XXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't specify security group names for VPC launch (`setSecurityGroups`). For a non-default VPC, **you must use security group IDs** instead. See EC2 [run-instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html) page (`withSecurityGroupIds` , or `--security-group-ids` from CLI).

> When you specify a security group for a nondefault VPC to the CLI or the API actions, you must use the security group ID and **not** the security group name to identify the security group.

See: [Security Groups for EC2-VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#vpc-security-groups)

Related:

- [Terraform throws "groupName cannot be used with the parameter subnet" or "VPC security groups may not be used for a non-VPC launch"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31569910/55075)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@slayedbylucifer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22370878/55075) for his `ruby` code, here's the `java` solution for reference:

```
// Creates an instance in the specified subnet of a non-default VPC and using the
// security group with id sg-1234567
ec2.runInstances(new RuntInstancesRequest()
    ...
    .withSubnetId("subnet-1234abcd")
    .withSecurityGroupIds("sg-1234567"));
```